# How to custom a classloader

Tags: classloader

I'm trying to implementing this function with a customer classloader: I have some class files in a alternatives.jar file, they provide different implementation than normal implementation. i.e., each class in this jar, has another version which in other jar file -- also get loaded in the classpath.

I know it's better to use instrument API to achieve same purpose. But now my concern is I need to understand why I'm failing.

So this is my method:
1. define a AlternativeClassLoader.java, in this file, I override findClass method. So if the class name can be found from alternatives.jar, then use the version from alternatives.jar.
2. in constructor, I have called super(null) so all these class loading work will be performed by my classloader, rather that system's.
3. This (seems to be true) also requires me to load other classes (if they're not system one). So I have to parse classpath, find all classes which indicated by the classpath.

My problem is, I can load my alternative class, everything seems to be fine...However, I'm using slf4j which yells the following error:

```
Failed to auto configure default logger context
Reported exception:
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser configuration error occurred

Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
```

Reported exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getLoader(ResourceBundle.java:431)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:841)
```

I doubt this is caused by my bad classloader implementation. Would somebody help me out? Many thanks!

This is my classloader:

```
public class AlternativeClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private static final String ALTERNATIVE_JAR_PROPERTY = "alternativejar";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AlternativeClassLoader.class);

    private Map<String, Class<?>> clzCache = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    private Map<String, String> others = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private Set<String> alternativesRegistry;
    private JarFile altjar;

    public AlternativeClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        /*
         * pass null so I can incept all class loading except system's. By doing
         * this you'll need to override findClass
         */
        super(null);
        registerAlternatives();
        registerOthers();
    }

    /**
     * This method will parse classpath and get all non-system class name, and
     * build classname - jar_file_path/file_system_path mappings
     */
    private void registerOthers() {
        String[] paths = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(":");
        URL[] urls = new URL[paths.length];

        for (String path : paths) {
            if (path.endsWith("*.jar")) {
                registerClass(path, others);
            } else {
                File f = new File(path);
                if (!f.isDirectory())
                    continue;

                File[] classFiles = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File arg0) {
                        if (arg0.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                for (File file : classFiles) {
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    String className = fileName.substring(0,
                            fileName.lastIndexOf("."));

                    others.put(className, file.getPath());
                }
            }
        }

        showRegistry(
                "Me will also be responsible for loading the following classes:",
                others);
    }

    private void registerClass(String path, Map<String, String> registry) {
        try {
            JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
            for (JarEntry entry = jis.getNextJarEntry(); entry != null; entry = jis
                    .getNextJarEntry()) {
                if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class") && !entry.isDirectory()) {
                    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String part : entry.getName().split("/")) {
                        if (className.length() != 0)
                            className.append(".");
                        className.append(part);

                        if (part.endsWith(".class"))
                            className.setLength(className.length()
                                    - ".class".length());
                    }

                    registry.put(className.toString(), path);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            logger.error(
                    "Failed when read/parse jar {}. Your class file may not been replaced by alternative implementation",
                    path, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to find alternative class implementation from jar file specified by
     * ALTERNATIVE_JAR_PROPERTY. If it's not specified, then use same jar file
     * where this classloader is loaded.
     */
    private void registerAlternatives() {
        String jarFilePath = System.getProperty(ALTERNATIVE_JAR_PROPERTY);

        if (jarFilePath == null || jarFilePath.isEmpty()) {
            URL url = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                    .getLocation();
            System.out.println(url + ":" + url.toString());
            jarFilePath = url.getPath();
        }

        try {
            altjar = new JarFile(jarFilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("cannot read jar {}", jarFilePath);
            return;
        }

        Map<String, String> registry = new HashMap<String, String>();
        registerClass(jarFilePath, registry);

        alternativesRegistry = registry.keySet();

        showRegistry("===Found the following alternative class:===", registry);
    }

    private void showRegistry(String string, Map<String, String> registry) {
        System.out.println(string);

        for (String clzName : registry.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("Class:%30s ->%s\n", clzName,
                    registry.get(clzName));
        }
    }

    private Class<?> myLoadClass(String name) throws IOException,
    ClassFormatError {
        logger.debug("myload class {}", name);
        System.out.printf("myload class %s\n", name);

        if (alternativesRegistry.contains(name) && altjar != null) {
            JarEntry entry = altjar.getJarEntry(name + ".class");
            InputStream is = altjar.getInputStream(entry);
            return readClassData(name, is);
        }

        String path = others.get(name);

        if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (path.endsWith(".jar")) {
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(path);
            JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry(name + ".class");
            InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(entry);
            return readClassData(name, is);
        } else {// it's a folder, need to read clz from .class file
            System.out.printf("file path for %s is %s\n", name, path);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            return readClassData(name, is);
        }
    }

    private Class<?> readClassData(String name, InputStream is)
            throws IOException, ClassFormatError {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length);
        int len = is.read(buffer);
        while (len > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            len = is.read(buffer);
        }

        Class<?> clz = defineClass(name, out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());

        if (clz != null) {
            System.out.printf("loaded %s by me\n", name);
            clzCache.put(name, clz);
        }
        return clz;
    }

    protected Class<?> findCachedClass(String name)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> clz = clzCache.get(name);

        if (clz == null) {
            clz = findLoadedClass(name);
        }

        return clz;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("findClass: " + name);

        Class<?> cls = findCachedClass(name);

        if (cls == null) {
            try {
                cls = myLoadClass(name);
            } catch (ClassFormatError | IOException e) {
                logger.error("failed to load class {}", name, e);
                System.out.printf("failed to load class %s\n", name);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return cls;
    }
}
```

I have tried to override findResource(), but it's never called.

This is how I put my classloader into use:

```
java -Djava.system.class.loader=AlternativeClassLoader -classpath=.:./alternatives.jar:./slf4j-xxx.jar Test
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem. The tricky is:

1. Never use any package other than java.*. Otherwise, it will cause recursively loading ...IllegalState error.
2. In your classloader constructor, load all the alternative class and cache them.
3. In your constructor, call super(parent) other than super(null), then you don't need to do all the class loading stuff, the parent classloader can do it for you.
4. in override findClass(), if the class can be found from cache (means they have alternative implementation), then return it, otherwise let super.findClass do the rest for you.

so the following is the source code:

```
public class AlternativeClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private static final String ALTERNATIVE_JAR_PROPERTY = "alternativejar";
    private Map<String, Class<?>> clzCache = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    public AlternativeClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
        loadAlternativeClasses();
    }
    private void loadAlternativeClasses() {
        String jarFilePath = System.getProperty(ALTERNATIVE_JAR_PROPERTY);
        if (jarFilePath == null || jarFilePath.isEmpty()){
            URL url = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
            System.out.println(url + ":" + url.toString());
            jarFilePath = url.getPath();
        }

        JarInputStream jis;
        try {
            jis = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarFilePath));
            JarEntry entry;
            while ((entry = jis.getNextJarEntry()) != null){
                String className = entry.getName();
                className = className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length());
                System.out.printf("loading class from %s: %s\n", jarFilePath, className);
                readClassData(className, jis);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   private Class<?> readClassData(String name, InputStream is) throws IOException,
            ClassFormatError {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length);
        int len = is.read(buffer);
        while (len > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            len = is.read(buffer);
        }
        Class<?> clz = defineClass(name, out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());
        if (clz != null) {
            System.out.printf("loaded %s by myself\n", name);
            clzCache.put(name, clz);
        }
        return clz;
    }
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("findClass: " + name);
        Class<?> cls = clzCache.get(name);
        if (cls == null)
            cls = super.findClass(name);

        return cls;
    } 
}
```